# colspan is not working if i have multiple tbody

Tags: html

If I use multiple **tbody** within a table and assign colspan to **th, td**.
The colspan is not applied to the **td** and **th** in **tr**.
Here is the sample code:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>The th colspan attribute</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
  
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

if anyone know where am i making mistake please let me know... thank you in advance...

Comment: `colspan` is set correctly. The problem is that the first column of each row has got `5` colspan value (so same). So it seems nothing is implemented, but it's implemented correctly. To see if it is set correctly, pls try to add new table row with 6 columns. then you will now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `colspan` is working as per expected. Multiple `tbody` is not creating any issue. I have modified the table layout a little bit to demonstrate how `colspan` is occupying space of 5 cols.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>The th colspan attribute</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
    <th>col 3</th>
    <th>col 4</th>
    <th>col 5</th>
    <th>col 6</th>
    <th>col 7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">February</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your example, the columns are not taking more space because your table only have two columns. Therefore, the code `colspan="5"` won't expand to 5 cols. It will expand to 5 columns only if one of the table row had 6 cols.

**Note**: `colspan` determines how many columns a cell overlaps, not the size of those columns. Use the CSS width property to specify the width of things.

Comment: cool... thanks for the answer... need to focus on basic...i will follow these answer...